# logging into a specific hpc node from jupyter notebook in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, hpc, vscode-remote

I work on an HPC where we have a login node to login and then we can ask for a specific amount of computing resources which will then be allocated on compute node. We cannot run our programs in login node since it is shared. Currently, if we want to run jupyter on the compute node, we have to ssh into the compute node and forward the port.
Is there any way to ssh into compute node so that we can run the jupyter notebook from vs code itself? If I run it directly it will run in login node which is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can ssh into a compute node that is accessible through a login node by setting up your VSCode ssh config file such that your login node is a ProxyJump and your compute node the host you want to ssh to.

If you would log in to your login node as `ssh username@ip.of.login.node`, and from the login node, you can ssh to the compute node as `ssh ip.of.compute.node`, then you can set up your config file as such:

```
Host loginnode
    HostName ip.of.login.node
    User meulemeester
  
Host computenode
    HostName ip.of.compute.node
    User meulemeester
    ProxyCommand ssh -vv -W %h:%p <ip.of.login.node>
    # -W flag is necessary to redirect stdin and stdout
    # %h:%p is hostname and portname. Host refers to ProxyJump (i.e. loginnode), port is 22 by default
    ProxyJump loginnode
```

Make sure that this config file is the file used when running `ssh`. Check the VSCode setting `Remote.SSH: config file` to see if it points to this config file. Instead of using the IPs fo the login node or compute node, you can also use the host names directly (i.e. anything you would put after the @ when ssh'ing).

Depending on the authorisation methods, you may want to add additional parameters to the config file. The given setup works if the host has the public key of the local machine stored under `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

The compute node should now be available as an option when you want to connect to a host in VSCode.